# struts action mapping action input attribute

Tags: java, struts-config

I am a noob when it comes to Java and Struts ( I feel like .Net boy in Java world ).

What is the input attribute on the action element used for?  So in the example below the input is someinput.jsp.

```
<action path="/somepath" 
        type="SomeAction" 
        name="SomeForm" 
        scope="session"
        input="someinput.jsp">
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the form bean `SomeForm` returns validation errors, it will return the page `someinput.jsp`. To quote the [corresponding DTD](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/tags/STRUTS_ACTION_1_3_0/conf/java/struts-config_1_3.dtd):

> Valid only when "name" is specified. Required if "name" is specified
>   and the input bean returns validation errors. Optional if "name" is
>   specified and the input bean does not return validation errors.

Answer (score 4):

Struts will forward the user to the page/action specified in the `input` attribute if validation fails on the form specified in the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the above, it is also possible in your action execution (whether it is a single unit of action, or multiple units of action), to specify the result, i.e. `SUCCESS`, `FAILURE`, or `INPUT`.

Answer (score 0):

Struts validator plug-in will intecept the created form bean instance from the view and does   validation before going to controller and if the data is against the end-user validation rules then  errors object is digested in input attribute view which is specified as a value

Answer (score 0):

It's for redirection to the jsp in the input attribute. But in your Action controller you need to specify mapping.getInputForward() instead of mapping.findForward().

Struts-config file:

```
<action input="test.jsp"
        name="testActionForm"
        path="/test" 
        scope="session"      type="package.TestActionController">
</action>
```

Action Controller:

```
public ActionForward doMethod(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return mapping.getInputForward();
}
```